# IPC in Fortran?

Tags: c, fortran, ipc

I am trying to do IPC between a Fortran and C program. So far I have found good documentation for IPC in Linux using C but can't find any help with Fortran.

Is this possible to do IPC between a Fortrans and then a Fortran and C program?

Thanks
B

Comment: you can call C functions from Fortran, preferably using ISO C binding.

Comment: Yes but the other C program is a parallel program and needs to work on a cluster. The inputs to this C program is provided from a Fortran program -_-

Comment: you're saying you know how to do IPC under Linux in C, which is basically calling some functions from a C library. So, you can just call those from within Fortran.

Comment: The lowest common denominator for IPC is a *file*.  It isn't clear at all whether that's appropriate or not, it certainly is the least troublesome way to get IPC with Fortran going.  Beats punch cards.

Comment: If your parallel program uses MPI you could also use that for IPC between the Fortran and C programs.

Comment: Someone can probably point you to an example if you specify what type of IPC you are looking for: shared memory, message passing, semaphores, pipes etc

Answer (score -1):

You can from Fortran 2003 onwards.

In terms of Inter Process Communication, you use objects like pipes. A pipe is basically a read,write,(or both) object and typically what happens is that programs create specially named pipes, and then each process will get the appropriate handle and then send and receive data to it, as if it was like a network connection.

EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE runs a shell command, synchronously or asynchronously.

You could try the code found on this page:
http://www.jcameron.com/vms/fortran.htm

The programs are:

MAILBOX_A.FOR
MAILBOX_B.FOR

Comment: I don't dispute the truth of this though, strictly speaking, IPC between Fortran and C has been possible since C came along, given enough time and patience.  But I think this answer would be much improved with a little, or even a lot of, explanation.  As it is it adds little to the comments already made.